# Применить :nth-child() только к видимым блокам таблицы

Tags: css

Вот это кусок кода форматирует таблицу по типу зебры:

```css
#calc tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #f0f0f0; /* Цвет фона */
}

#calc tr:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  background: #666; /* Цвет фона */
  color: #fff; /* Цвет текста */
}
```

```html
<table id="calc">
  <tr>
    <td>Кол-во трубы на ворота</td>
    <td id="truba_na_vorota"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="display: none;">
    <td>Кол-во трубы на рамку ворот</td>
    <td id="tr_na_vorota_ramka"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Кол-во трубы на калитку</td>
    <td id="tr_na_kalitku"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Кол-во трубы на что-то ещё</td>
    <td id="tr_na_drugoe"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Но есть одна проблема: если в таблице присутствуют поля со свойством `display:none`, то вышеуказанные стили так же применяются к ним, в итоге зебра получается неправильной.

То есть, получается так:
1 - это белый,
2 - серый (display: none),
3 - белый,
4 - серый, и т.д.

В итоге, выводятся 2 белых поля подряд.

Как сделать, чтобы `nth-child` применялся только для видимых полей?
Возможны и другие решения.

P.S. `display:none` применяется динамически.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Если все строки однострочные и не требуется менять цвет шрифта, можно использовать `repeating-linear-gradient`, но следует обратить внимание на плохую поддержку браузерами.

```css
table {
  line-height: 2em;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(silver 0, silver 2em, antiquewhite 2em, antiquewhite 4em);
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="calc">
  <tr>
    <td>Кол-во трубы на ворота</td>
    <td id="truba_na_vorota"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="display: none;">
    <td>Кол-во трубы на рамку ворот</td>
    <td id="tr_na_vorota_ramka"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Кол-во трубы на калитку</td>
    <td id="tr_na_kalitku"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Кол-во трубы на что-то ещё</td>
    <td id="tr_na_drugoe"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

`nth-child` и `nth-of-type` считают по номеру в дереве элементов. Им всё равно, какие у элементов стили, потому что номер элемента от этого не меняется.

Следовательно, чтобы воспользоваться `nth-of-type`, надо динамически менять тип элемента. Например, `tr` на `div` и обратно.

В коде для наглядности строки не исчезают. Чекбоксы окрашивают их в серый цвет и исключают из зебры. Если снять галку в чекбоксе, строка вернётся обратно в зебру.

Чтобы решить поставленную в вопросе задачу, надо заменить `<div style="background: #ccc;">` на `<div style="display: none;">`.

```js
$(function (){
  $('input:checkbox').click(function () {
    // Хотим менять tr на div и обратно. 
    // Для этого будем заворачивать ячейки то в tr, то в div.
    // Чтобы не потерять ячейки, которые стоят в одном ряду с чекбоксом, 
    // сначала накручиваем новую обёртку поверх старой:
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $(this).parent().parent().wrap('<div style="background: #ccc;"></div>');
    }
    else {
      $(this).parent().parent().wrap('<tr></tr>');
    }
    // а потом уже выкидываем старую упаковку:
    $(this).parent().unwrap();
  });
});
```

```css
#calc tr { display: block; }
#calc tr:nth-of-type(2n) { background: #ff6; }
#calc tr:nth-of-type(2n+1) { background: #6ff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="calc">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Кол-во трубы на ворота</td>
    <td id="truba_na_vorota"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Кол-во трубы на рамку ворот</td>
    <td id="tr_na_vorota_ramka"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Кол-во трубы на калитку</td>
    <td id="tr_na_kalitku"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Кол-во трубы на что-то ещё</td>
    <td id="tr_na_drugoe"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Dikkiy Решает ли мой ответ вашу задачу? Что надо учесть или доработать?

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю следующий код для случая, если спрятаны только одна или две строки (работает на chromium). Для других случаев можно добавить дополнительные селекторы (закономерность видно из кода), но универсального решения я не знаю:

```css
#calc tr:nth-child(2n), #calc tr[style*="display: none"] ~ tr:nth-child(2n + 1), #calc tr[style*="display: none"] ~ tr[style*="display: none"] ~ tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #f0f0f0; /* Цвет фона */
  color: inherit; /* Цвет текста */
}

#calc tr:nth-child(2n + 1), #calc tr[style*="display: none"] ~ tr:nth-child(2n), #calc tr[style*="display: none"] ~ tr[style*="display: none"] ~ tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: #666; /* Цвет фона */
  color: #fff; /* Цвет текста */
}
```

```html
<table id="calc">
  <tr>
    <td>Кол-во трубы на ворота</td>
    <td id="truba_na_vorota"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="display: none;">
    <td>Кол-во трубы на рамку ворот</td>
    <td id="tr_na_vorota_ramka"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Кол-во трубы на калитку</td>
    <td id="tr_na_kalitku"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="display: none;">
    <td>Кол-во трубы на что-то ещё</td>
    <td id="tr_na_drugoe1">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Кол-во трубы на что-то ещё</td>
    <td id="tr_na_drugoe2">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Кол-во трубы на что-то ещё</td>
    <td id="tr_na_drugoe3">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: sercxjo, в том то и дело, что там не одно скрытое поле :(

Comment: Ну можно добавить селекторы `tr[style*="display: none"] ~ tr[style*="display: none"] ~ ` и для двух спрятанных, трёх и т.д.  меняя каждый раз  2n и 2n+1.